# Installing python into a portable, self-contained directory on the network

Tags: python, sys.path

I need to install python 2.7 and 3.4 for linux/unix (built from source) into a directory on the network other than the location from which it will ultimately be used.

I.e. the directory containing the installation must be portable and self-contained.

Thus, it seems like things such as the "installation-dependent default" sys.path should be defined relative to the current location of the python installation.

However, --prefix and --exec_prefix require absolute paths.

For example: 
I might create the installation in "/stage/tools/python", then copy the "python" directory to "/tools/knights/ni". If I then invoke "/tools/knights/ni/$platform/bin/python", python should find everything it needs from its installation under "/tools/knights/ni/"

How can I do a portable, self-contained install?

Thanks much for any guidance.

Comment: It would help to know more specifically what you are trying to solve. Why do you need a binary, relocatable build (as opposed to, say, a build script and letting the users compile it)?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably not be able to do portable (as in: works across different OS versions, archs), but `virtualenv` can help you create self-contained installations.

Virtualenv has a `--relocatable` option that solves the case if the mountpoints differ, but it has issues according to the documentation, and I never used it. However, virtualenv is sort of a hack that forces Python to do something it was not designed to do (being moved to a self-contained directory) and you always end up shooting yourself in the foot with it.

What I would have preferred is to just do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to easily install all the dependencies. That, and/or [Docker](https://www.docker.io). If you need to patch Python itself or have a custom build configuration, I have preferred to just let the users do `./configure && make && make install` themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Even just focusing on a single platform, there doesn't seem to be a  way to build a relocatable python without hacking the build process.   I have no control over where users will copy the directory containing the python installation. It seems like there should be a standard way to  build/install a relocatable python.

Comment: Also, I don't want to use a virtualenv, even with --relocatable, because I expect users to make their own virtualenvs from my installation, and I understand there are problems with creating virtualenvs from other virtualenvs.  Some related links I found that seem to try to address this need in one way or another:  [http://cd-docdb.fnal.gov/0051/005182/001/relocatable-python.pdf]  and [https://github.com/Infinidat/relocatable-python3].

Comment: [virtualenv-clone](https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone) can help you with letting the user create virtualenvs.